# Check Zod types are equivalent to a TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript, zod

Ive been asserting that the results of an API call have this shape in TypeScript:

```
interface Res {
  films: string;
  people: string;
}

const res: Res = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/")
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then(({ films, people }) => {
    return {
      films,
      people,
    };
  });
```

Later I added runtime type checking with Zod

```
const resSchema = z.object({
  films: z.string(),
  people: z.string(),
});

resSchema.parse(res);
```

This works but it means that I have 2 different type definitions to maintain. Is there a way of checking in TypeScript that the type of `resSchema` is equal to `Res`?

I know that zod can infer:

```
    type ResType = z.infer<typeof resSchema>

    const res: ResType = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(({ films, people }) => {
        return {
          films,
          people,
        };
      });
```

However I dont want to use this as I cant at a glance as easily see the fields on `ResType` compared to `Res` which is very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by asserting the type of the schema rather than inferring the types from the schema. In your example, if you already have your `Res` interface, you can define your `schema` as:

```js
import { z } from "zod";

interface Res {
  films: string;
  people: string;
}

const schema: z.ZodType<Res> = z.object({
  films: z.string(),
  people: z.string(),
});
```

If you update `Res` you will get a type error on the line where you defined `schema` that the `z.object` value is no longer assignable to the `ZodType` you specified.

This also has a nice property that the return value from `schema.parse` will be shown as `Res` in your editor as well. If you give the interface a meaningful name and javadoc style comments, they will be conferred to the return values from `parse` in your editor's language server.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFA9NXAFICuAzvCAIYDWwAdgOZwYAC159mcRmCzRBI5gDoKvGAFMomdgGMVcAGLAANiABKK5pB7MdCCnDjUAVA72GQ4gO7BhsneZWbgTGAVYkEvAx0HalssV2YALjhWKFFKO0dnAAUVCDAIuE9vYR0YcMjouzAcvJVE5NSKNCpNCEt4Zk0hFQ5E5HkALRIAFQBPKoAefSNTc1arAD44AF4UeQgAIwArfxgAChs7IKME1fr+XYBKABoYqtyI3vkzvkubtAvKCha2uCgzCysyySnW67HkYHYUCs+1ix0S+CGXTgAFl2DAUgAPfBXOB3GrwgDSKnYPEYcFMKgAbmYcQBhSEpFQAWgAgjweDpkRBmMwcQAZdiMP48bQuZhCdZCjn4d6UWh2OwAPQA-EA)

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer from @Souperman works, it does not account for `null`, `undefined`, or optional properties (`?`).

So I started looking for a solution that would...

**SOLUTION 1:**

This will account for `null`, `undefined`, or optional properties (`?`).

It uses the "tozod" package. See here for [github](https://github.com/colinhacks/tozod) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tozod).

You can use it like this:

```TypeScript
import { z } from "zod";
import { toZod } from "tozod";

interface Res {
  films?: string; // Note that "films" is now optional
  people: string;
}

const schema: toZod<Res> = z.object({
  films: z.string().optional(), // removing .optional() will throw an error
  people: z.string(),
});
```

I like this solution, but I recently discovered it [doesn't handle union well](https://github.com/colinhacks/tozod/issues/4).

Which is when I found solution 2...

**SOLUTION 2:**

This is an alternate option, but just like the answer from @Souperman, it does NOT account for `null`, `undefined`, or optional properties (`?`).

I found this solution in [this zod issue thread](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1495). TS 4.9+ is required.

Using the new TS `satisfies` keyword with `z.ZodType` we can check that a Zod Type matches the TypeScript interface. Errors will throw if they do not match.

For example:

```TypeScript
type User = {
    id: number
    name: string
    age: number
}

const UserSchema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    name: z.string(),
    age: z.number()
}) satisfies z.ZodType<User>
```

This is a cool solution, but it's not good for me since it doesn't account for `null`, `undefined`, and optional properties.

**SOLUTION 3:**

I am currently looking into [superstructjs](https://docs.superstructjs.org/) instead of zod because someone on zod thread suggested it. Will report back with more later!

Comment: The "satisfies" is also useful for my use case - I get zod types auto-generated from openAPI schemas using https://github.com/astahmer/openapi-zod-client so I don't want to modify them, as I want to re-generate them when the API changes.